# fs watch triggering two times on a singe change

Tags: node.js

I am just starting into NodeJS and this is the very first example I coded.

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.watch('target.txt', () => {
    console.log('File target.txt just changed..');
});
console.log('Now watching target.txt for changes');
```

When I do `echo 'Hello..' >> target.txt`, I see my console log happening two times.

Why is that strange behaviour.

I am using node **v8.12.0**

Comment: `fs.watch('target.txt', (eventType, filename) => ...` what are those two values when the callback is invoked each time?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts each time `eventType = change` and `filename = target.xt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Node's [documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener) for `fs.watch(filename[, options][, listener])`:

**Known Caveats**:

The `fs.watch` API is not **100% consistent across platforms**, and is unavailable in some situations.The recursive option is only supported on `macOS` and `Windows`.

Additionally, `Windows` has a known design [issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/1970) where *two callbacks are fired for writes into a file*. This is validated in a similar post [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978924/fs-watch-fired-twice-when-i-change-the-watched-file)

`fs.watch` is *just a buggy api on node's part leading to inconsistent behavior*.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: I am seeing `File target.txt changed..` twice. It is random, sometimes it is just one log sometimes it log twice.

Comment: Ahh I see, are you on windows or macintosh?

Comment: For what it's worth, I ran this on my mac and it did indeed show twice.

Comment: @Phix Yes I am on Mac

Answer (score 2):

Adding a small time limit will keep `fs.watch()` from being handled twice. It will still be triggered twice, but the handling is only run once within the specified interval.

```
const fs = require('fs');

// handle once within a specified interval (milliseconds)
const interval = 100;
let time = new Date().getTime();

fs.watch('target.txt', () => {
  let now = new Date().getTime();
  if (now - time > interval) {
    time = now;

    // handle the change
    console.log('File target.txt just changed..');
  }
});
console.log('Now watching target.txt for changes');
```