# fs.watch fires three times instead of expected two

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm aware from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12979775/19754201) other StackOverflow answer that `fs.watch()` fires twice on some operating systems (I'm on Windows 11). The weird thing though however, is that while `fs.watch()` fires twice for me with a new setup and almost empty file, it fires *three* times for me when I'm running it in a complex/large script. [Here](https://github.com/rpaladin/rpaladin.github.io/blob/main/make.js#L81-L83) is my complex script. I don't believe that it's a loop cycle issue, because 1) it returns `console.logs` in my `fs.watch()` function 2) it returns `console.logs()` directly inside the function that should be run after `fs.watch()` is triggered. For those interested I put a `console.log()` between [these](https://github.com/rpaladin/rpaladin.github.io/blob/main/make.js#L25-L26) lines.

To put it into summary, I'd like to know whether three pulses is expected behavior on top of stated two pulses, and if it's not normal behavior, how to fix my code to restrict it only to two pulses, if possible.

Comment: What are you doing to trigger it at all? What operation in what application? To restrict it, just try creating some timeouts and de-duplicate multiple calls.

Comment: If you're getting three pulses it basically does mean some application did 3 distinct operations.

Comment: I'm running the operation via Windows commandline with Node.js. The fs.watch() function is set to trigger when one or more files in the stated directory is modified. I don't think the three pulses are caused by three operations - I tested in a separate setup with a almost thread-bare script, which triggers twice (not thrice). It's a known Node.js issue as stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978924/fs-watch-fired-twice-when-i-change-the-watched-file/12979775#12979775 which I have also verified with several other sources. Do you really think timeouts could be the answer?

Comment: Yeah but as you can see from the thread you linked, they are *multiple calls to the windows API*. Those are the operations I was talking about. You didn't state what the operation was though, 'modified' can mean many things. What is modifying it and how?

Comment: And yes if you want to deduplicate multiple events coming in, you should either wait a bit to see if more events come in, or immediately trigger and remember which were recently triggered. The latter can be problematic because I assume you want to do something with the files, so it's better to wait till all the operations are done.

Comment: By operation I mean whichever function or method is set to execute if `fs.watch()` is triggered. By modified I mean addition or removal of characters in a HTML file for example (any file content to be exact). As I stated in my initial post, the three pulses are being triggered whether I put it inside the fs.watch() function as a event, or a function executed by the event. The reason why I'm hesitant to implement timeouts is because the watch function runs in real-time and I don't wish for any changes to go undetected due to by-interval-frame checks, rather then instant checks.

Comment: Typically file operations are multi-step processes, each of those trigger events and utilities like fsevents fire on each of them. Some applications will do the 'touch' system call first, others will have multiple systems calls to write chunks, some delete the old version, write a file in a different place and then move it in place, and some operating systems will lock a file before writing.

Comment: Why are you worried that using a timeout (aka setTimeout) won't trigger? It's pretty reliable.

Comment: On second glance, I think I was confusing the method setTimeout() with setInverval(). My mistake.

Comment: setTimeout() works for me. This post especially helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18808697/19754201. If you'd like to post an answer, I'll upvote it and mark it as this thread's solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is described as expected behavior [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/1970#issuecomment-2599352).

> What you see as "one" modification is really numerous calls to the Win32 API. Since there is no transaction to bucket all of the calls together, the filesystem is forced to send out multiple notifications for various kernel calls.

So when using fs.watch on Windows, expect multiple calls to be made for a single modification.

---

[Chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar) is the only alternative I know of which does watching very well.