# How to monitor file modification under Windows environment in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

First I tried `fs.watch()` according to API doc of Node.js, but it will report the event twice even though I just modified the file it monitors once. Then I did some google search and find [chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar), it has the same problem as `fs.watch()`, although it works fine in Linux machine.

Comment: You can try nodemon https://github.com/remy/nodemon

Comment: I think you must misunderstand my point. In fact, I was trying to write a little node.js app to watch file modification in a specific directory,once the file under that directory has been modified, then I need to zip them all to a tar ball. I have no any to plan to re-start my node app.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/bevry/watchr, but it may consume more CPU than fs.watch

Comment: Are the events really identical? If not, you could ignore one of them. You could have a look at the source code of some of the watchers, e.g. grunt-watch plugin.

Comment: I'd just keep a map of last modifications for each file in the directory -- and if it hasn't changed, don't update (http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why fs.watchFile called twice in Node?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468504/why-fs-watchfile-called-twice-in-node)